# Cómo definir función para remover ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, objeto

tengo que definir la función handleRemove = () => {} para llegara remover el id. lo tengo colocado en el button, pero no se como llegar al id, para removerlo, su apoyo por favor. me pide definirlo, lo tengo declarado, pero no lo estoy ejecutando correctamente. creo que no esta declarado correctamente. es para el objeto de EL ID DE BENEFICIOS., devo poder remover el id de cada item de beneficios, espero que este claro. Necesito llegar a remover el id de beneficios por cada clic del button Handleremove.

Gracias.

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { store } from "../store";

const isSameItem = (descripcion) => (item) => item.descripcion === descripcion;

const ITEMS_BENEFITS_DROP_DOWN = [
  { id: "0000", descripcion: "Condiciones estándares" },
  { id: "0001", descripcion: "Descuento 11x12" },
  { id: "0002", descripcion: "Descuento 13x12" },
  { id: "0003", descripcion: "Migración Pago por Kilómetros" },
  { id: "0004", descripcion: "SOAT gratis" },
];

const BENEFITS_DETAIL = {
  beneficio: "No usa el seguro, lo retomará más adelante",
};

const BENEFICIOS = {
  CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES: {
    data: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "Condiciones estándares",
        information:
          "A las pólizas financiadas en 12 meses se les modifica a 11 y a la prima anual se le brinda un <b>descuento del 8.3%</b> para no modificar el monto mensual.",
        down_payment: "$486",
        total_payment: "$286",
        discount: "-8.3%",
        terms: {
          term_1:
            "Sólo aplica para clientes sin pagos pendientes o que tengan solo 1 cuota pendiente.",
          term_2: "Refinanciamiento de pago al mes siguiente.",
          term_3: "Vehículos con máximo 1 siniestro.",
          term_4: "Es compatible con el Descuento 13x12.",
          term_5: "No aplica con migraciones.",
          term_6: "Válido para Lima y provincias.",
        },
        suggested:
          "Estimado(a) [nombre del cliente], entiendo las dificultades que podría tener para realizar el pago debido a la coyuntura que estamos viviendo, por...",
      },
    ],
    disabled: [],
  },
};

const StepThree = ({ setStep }) => {
  const LeftContent = () => (
    <div className="stepTwo leftContent">
      <div className="btn-back" onClick={() => setStep(2)}></div>
      <h2>
        <b>Beneficios</b> a brindar
      </h2>
      <p>Elige el beneficio que deseas brindarle a tu cliente.</p>
      <div className="separator"></div>
      <div className="policieDetail">
        <div className="policieDetail__title">MOTIVO ELEGIDO</div>
        <div className="policieDetail__code">{BENEFITS_DETAIL.beneficio}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const RightContent = () => {
    const [selectedReason, setSelectedReason] = useState([]);
    const { dispatch } = useContext(store);
    const handleChangeReason = (val) => {
      if (selectedReason.some(isSameItem(val))) {
        const items = selectedReason.filter(
          (s) => s.descripcion !== val.descripcion
        );
        setSelectedReason(items);
      } else {
        if (!val) return;
        const item = ITEMS_BENEFITS_DROP_DOWN.find(isSameItem(val.descripcion));
        if (item) {
          const n = selectedReason.concat(item);
          setSelectedReason(n.reverse());
        }
      }
    };

    const handleBtnContinue = () => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_INFO", payload: selectedReason });
      setStep(4);
    };

    const handleRemove = () => {
      console.log('llegar al ID');
    }

    return (
      <div className="stepTwo rightContent">
        <div>
          <h2>Elige el beneficio</h2>
          <div className="benefit-reason">
            <p>
              Los beneficios van de acuerdo al <span>motivo elegido.</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <DropdownInput
          items={ITEMS_BENEFITS_DROP_DOWN}
          onDropdownSelectItem={handleChangeReason}
          // loading = {false}
          label="Beneficios a brindar"
          name="beneficios"
        />

        {selectedReason.map((s, id) => (
          <React.Fragment key={id}>
            {s.descripcion === "Condiciones estándares" && (
              <React.Fragment>
                {BENEFICIOS.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES.data.map((item) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <div className="benefits-detail">
                      <div className="box-benefits-detail">
                        <div className="benefits_header">
                          <div className="benefitsLabel">
                            <div className="benefitsLabel blue">beneficio</div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="benefitsRemove">
                            <span className="textRemove">eliminar</span>
                            <button
                              onClick={() => {
                                handleRemove();
                              }}
                              className="buttonRemove"
                            ></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="benefits_body">
                          <div className="benefits_title">{item.title}</div>
                          <p
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                              __html: item.information,
                            }}
                          ></p>
                          <div className="benefitsPrima_actual">
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_actual__tilte">
                              Prima total actual:
                            </div>
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_actual__amount">
                              {item.down_payment}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="benefitsPrima_total">
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_total__title">
                              Prima total con el beneficio aplicado:
                            </div>
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_total__amount">
                              {item.total_payment}{" "}
                              <span>({item.discount})</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="divider"></div>
                          <div className="benefitsList">
                            <ul>
                              <li>{item.terms.term_1}</li>
                              <li>{item.terms.term_2}</li>
                              
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="benefitsGuion">
                        <div className="benefitsGuion_img"></div>
                        <div className="benefitsGuion_content">
                          <div className="benefitsGuion_content__title">
                            GUIÓN SUGERIDO
                          </div>
                          <p
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.suggested }}
                          ></p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="BenefitsReadMore">
                          <button onClick={() => console.log("carga modal...")}>
                            leer más
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
            {s.descripcion === "Descuento 11x12" && (
              <React.Fragment>
                {BENEFICIOS.DESCUENTO_ONCE_POR_DOCE.data.map((item) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <div className="benefits-detail">
                      <div className="box-benefits-detail">
                        <div className="benefits_header">
                          <div className="benefitsLabel">
                            <div className="benefitsLabel blue">beneficio</div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="benefitsRemove">
                            <span className="textRemove">eliminar</span>
                            <button
                              onClick={() => {
                                handleRemove();
                              }}
                              className="buttonRemove"
                            ></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="benefits_body">
                          <div className="benefits_title">{item.title}</div>
                          <p
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                              __html: item.information,
                            }}
                          ></p>
                          <div className="benefitsPrima_actual">
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_actual__tilte">
                              Prima total actual:
                            </div>
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_actual__amount">
                              {item.down_payment}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="benefitsPrima_total">
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_total__title">
                              Prima total con el beneficio aplicado:
                            </div>
                            <div className="benefitsPrima_total__amount">
                              {item.total_payment}{" "}
                              <span>({item.discount})</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="divider"></div>
                          <div className="benefitsList">
                            <ul>
                              <li>{item.terms.term_1}</li>
                              <li>{item.terms.term_2}</li>
                             
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="benefitsGuion">
                        <div className="benefitsGuion_img"></div>
                        <div className="benefitsGuion_content">
                          <div className="benefitsGuion_content__title">
                            GUIÓN SUGERIDO
                          </div>
                          <p>{item.suggested}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="BenefitsReadMore">
                          <button onClick={() => console.log("carga modal...")}>
                            leer más
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}

        <button
          onClick={handleBtnContinue}
          className={`btn-brokers ${!selectedReason.length ? "disabled" : ""} pull-right`}
        >
          CONTINUAR
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Layout leftContent={<LeftContent />} rightContent={<RightContent />} />
  );
};

export default StepThree;
```

Edite y corregí el código nuevamente ahora ye me remueve, la consulta tengo 5 elementos a la hora que los remuevo y los vuelo a invocar ya no carga nuevamente los elementos hasta refrescar la página, es porque lo saco totalmente del state, bueno necesito que se remueva y que sean nuevamente invocados, no sé si se puede mejorar el código que deje, como comentó los borra pero ya no pudo  llamarlos nuevamente ,necesitó que se puedan llamar otra vez y no esperar recargar la página, me he percatado que el siguiente llamado el array y la data devuelve [0], creo que es por el nuevo estado que se genera, espero me puedan apoyar saludos, y Gracias

Aca la solución es volver llamar a los item.id removidos nuevamente para que vuevla a mostrarse, el contenido, alguna idea, lo necesitó en un select que vuelva a cargar su id y su contenido.

```js
const [beneficios, setBeneficios] = useState(BENEFICIOS);

const handleRemove = (itemId) => {
      // se filtran los items que tienen un id diferente al que se le esta pasando
      const NuevoEstadoCondiciones = beneficios.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES.data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
      const NuevoEstadoOncePorDoce = beneficios.DESCUENTO_ONCE_POR_DOCE.data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
      const NuevoEstadoTrecePorDoce = beneficios.DESCUENTO_TRECE_POR_DOCE.data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
      const NuevoEstadoMigracionPorKilometros = beneficios.MIGRACION_POR_KILOMETROS.data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
      const NuevoEstadoSoatGratis = beneficios.SOAT_GRATIS.data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);


       // se actualiza el estado
       setBeneficios((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES : {
          ...prevState.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES,
          data: NuevoEstadoCondiciones
        },
        DESCUENTO_ONCE_POR_DOCE : {
          ...prevState.DESCUENTO_ONCE_POR_DOCE,
          data: NuevoEstadoOncePorDoce
        },
        DESCUENTO_TRECE_POR_DOCE : {
          ...prevState.DESCUENTO_TRECE_POR_DOCE,
          data: NuevoEstadoTrecePorDoce
        },
        MIGRACION_POR_KILOMETROS : {
          ...prevState.MIGRACION_POR_KILOMETROS,
          data: NuevoEstadoMigracionPorKilometros
        },
        SOAT_GRATIS : {
          ...prevState.SOAT_GRATIS,
          data: NuevoEstadoSoatGratis
        }
      }));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas iterando de esta manera: `BENEFICIOS.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES.data.map((item)`, entonces dentro de item esta el `id`. Simplemente pasalo como parametro a `handleRemove` asi:

```
<div className="benefitsRemove">
   <span className="textRemove">eliminar</span>
      <button
          onClick={() => {
           handleRemove(item.id);
          }}
          className="buttonRemove">
      </button>
</div>
```

Y ya en tu funciona que maneja el borrado, seria algo asi:

```
const handleRemove = (id) => {
  console.log(`id a borrar ${id}`);
}
```

En esa funcion ya podrias hacer el `dispatch` para borrar.

Edit:
Si lo que quieres es borrarlo del estado de tu componente, tendrias que hacer unos cambios, como poner tu objeto `BENEFICIOS.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES` dentro del estado de tu componente `RightConent`.

```
const RightContent = () => {
    const [beneficios, setBeneficios] = useState(BENEFICIOS);`
```

Entonces en tu handler podrias filtrar esa info para quitar el id que se desea borrar:

```
const handleRemove = (idARemover) => {
  // se filtran los items que tienen un id diferente al que se le esta pasando
  const nuevoEstado = beneficios.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES.data.filter(id => id !== idARemover);

   // se actualiza el estado
   setBeneficios(prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES: {
          ...prevState.CONDICIONES_ESTANDARES,
          data: nuevoEstado
          }

   });
}
```

Comment: Hola Gracias , probare, y aviso, no me resultaba, voy a probar

Comment: si llega el id, correcto, apóyame por favor pero no solo para verlo en console, como lo remuevo, ralamente, le paso un state vacío algo asi, me puedes apoyar con la idea, Gracias

Comment: Todavía no lo quiero borrar en base al dispatch solo a nivel de react, eso será mas adelante.

Comment: Creo que con Filter() o Slice() Puedo hacer eso , no estoy seguro, me das una mano Gracias

Comment: actualice la respuesta con un ejemplo de como lo podrias hacer, no he probado que funcione pero es la idea.

Comment: si hay un pequeño error en le código,  de declaraciones, estoy varios días solo para resolver este punto del remove,

Comment: corregí el código pero no borra el contenido lo puse arriba puedes revisar que puede estar fallando, el evento llega, peor no lo elimina del state